# Eclipse plugin development - How to add Radio buttons in WizardNewFileCreationPage

Tags: eclipse-plugin, radio-button, wizard

I am using `WizardNewFileCreationPage` to create a *New File*

```java
public void addPages() {
    mainPage = new WizardNewFileCreationPage("FILE", getSelection());
    mainPage.setTitle("New File");
    mainPage.setDescription("Add new file"); 
    addPage(mainPage);
}
```

I want to add some *Radio Buttons* to it representing file extensions in this wizard so that users can select one of them as a file extension.

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WizardNewFileCreationPage` is not meant to be extended with custom controls. From its JavaDoc:

> Subclasses may override
>
> - `getInitialContents`
> - `getNewFileLabel`
>
> Subclasses may extend
>
> `handleEvent`

If you still want to add the radio buttons 'at your own risk', you can try to override `createAdvancedControls` and append you controls to the parent after calling `super`.

```java
protected void createAdvancedControls(Composite parent) {
  super.createAdvancedControls( parent );
  Button radioButton = new Button( parent, SWT.RADIO );
  // ...
}
```

Note that the layout of `parent` (currently) is a single-columned `GridLayout`, set the layout data accordingly.